# What determines the success of Axii / Persuasion / Intimidate?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Sometimes in dialog of The Witcher 2, Geralt gets the option to try to alter the course of the conversation with persuasion, intimidate, or the axii sign.

In practice, I've had intimidation fail to work, so I'm curious as to how the chance of success is determined in the first place. Is it related to the level of the abilities gained via use of the related mechanic? E.g., Axii Sign Hex increases when you use the Axii Sign to resolve a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to info listed on [IGN Vault](http://witchervault.ign.com/View.php?view=Editorials.Detail&id=8), you start with a 50/50 random chance of success for each one.

Each time you use one (either succeed or fail) it improves the skill (you'll see a message pop up about acquiring a new skill) thus improving your chance next time.

My person experience was that I succeeded the first/only three times I tried Axii and the first/only time I tried Persuasion, so either I'm very lucky, or it's not really 50/50...

Comment: Or you have a small sample size.

Comment: I looked through the article you linked; parts of it are flat out wrong. Specifically, the section regarding abilities. Strong Back is for letting Arayan LaVallette live, and Backstabber, actually Assassin, is for finding the Altair corpse in the courtyard. "Cover" can be gained even if you stray outside of the shield in Act 1. The parts regarding talented abilities may be right, but the legitimacy of the rest of it is now in question.

Comment: Indeed, 1/16 chance you're right and I was just lucky.  But I'm afraid I agree about the unreliable source.  My guess is they (IGN) had early/privileged access and started documenting a bunch of things that later changed before proper release.  Maybe try their procedure though - "C" for character screen and check the descriptions of the acquired abilities?